# Aligning drop-down menu in CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I can't seem to make the drop-down `<ul>` align with it's parent `<li>`.
What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<nav id="toolbar">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Section1</a></li>

        <li>
        <a href="#">Section2</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">SubA</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">Section3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">SubB</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Section4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#toolbar ul {list-style-type:none;
}

#toolbar ul li {display:block;
                position:relative;
                float:left;
                margin:0px 5px;
}

#toolbar li ul  {display:none;
}

#toolbar ul li:hover ul {display: block;
                      position:absolute;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5tbLh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul` elements have a default `padding-left` value applied by the user-agent, so by removing that you get the alignment you asked for (There is also a margin added by you, but I'm gonna ignored it since you've added it yourself).

```
#toolbar ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

or (if you want to target only the sub-menu):

```
#toolbar ul ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5tbLh/1/)

Comment: To add a bit more clarification: The <ul> is perfectly aligned with the parent <li> but receives padding that moves it's content items to the right.

Answer (score 0):

What adonis said was absolutely correct. There are certain other elements which take default padding and margin. So try using reset before styling any element.

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

if no list item of your page wants default bullets you may also include `list-style:none` in the above reset lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

There is `margin` and `padding` in this case (you add the margin yourself) which is affecting it.

### [View here for a fix](http://jsfiddle.net/7rgrM/)

### *[(this has outlines for more visual proof)](http://jsfiddle.net/7rgrM/1/)*

### CSS:

```
#toolbar ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#toolbar ul > li {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 5px;
}
#toolbar li ul {
    display:none;
}
#toolbar ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
}
#toolbar ul ul > li {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one i have pasted the code here

**HTML:**

```
<nav id="toolbar">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Section1</a></li>

        <li>
        <a href="#">Section2</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">SubA</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">Section3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">SubB</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Section4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
#toolbar ul {list-style-type:none;
}

#toolbar ul li {display:block;
                position:relative;
                float:left;
                margin:0px 5px;
}

#toolbar li ul  {display:none;
}

#toolbar ul li:hover ul {
                         display: block;
                         position:absolute;
}
#toolbar ul li:hover ul  li{
                         margin-left: -30px;

}
```